# Exponential diophantine equation that I’m curious about

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

For which $x,y \in \mathbb{N} $ does the following hold? $\forall k \in \mathbb{N} \exists a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\} : x^{a} + x^{b} = y^{c} + k y^{d} $. What sort of restrictions do we need on $x$ and $y$? I’ve tried considering when $x$ and $y$ are prime, then reducing the equation modulo $x$ , but I don’t know how to piece it together. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is probably false for any x and y (even if we remove cases like x=0 or x=1), just because the powers of x and y are so sparse.  For starters it shouldn't be too hard to prove that there are counterexamples if x=y.

Comment: I see your point. I’ll probably work on the case $x =y$ tonight. I’m really interested in the case $x =2$ and $y = 3$. Given this choice of $x$ and $y$, we arrive at $2^{a} + 2^{b} = 3^{c} + k3^{d}$, now, reducing this modulo 2, we arrive at $ 1 \equiv k$ mod 2.  I’m having trouble taking anything of use from this. Does this mean for any such $k$ the equation is satisfied? This seems fallacious, but I can’t place my finger on why.

Comment: Suppose $p$ is a prime which divides $x$ but not $y$. Then the above statement is false by taking $k=p$, since $x^a$, $x^b$ and $ky^d$ will be divisble by $p$, but $y^c$ will not be divisible by $p$. This covers $x=2, y=3$.

Comment: Indeed this is true, good point. I think I need to restrict the range of $k$. Could you offer some more insight into my comment above? Is it true that by reducing the equation modulo 2, then arriving at $1 \equiv k$ mod $2$, implies the equation is satisfied for any such k.